# Can I buy a PC part in the US and bring it back to Canada?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, canadian-residents

I'm currently on a vacation in the U.S (I live in Canada) and was wondering if I could buy PC parts from Micro Center and bring them back to Canada or if there are any additional fees.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, but it's not completely free. First, your [personal exemption](https://travel.gc.ca/returning/customs/bringing-to-canada/personal-exemptions-mini-guide) depends on how long you have been outside Canada. In short, approximately (the actual rules are in hours spent outside Canada):

- Same day: No exemption
- 1 or 2 days: Exemption up to $200
- 3 or more days: Exemption up to $800

That means you will have to pay duty and taxes on all goods above your exemption value. After you determine your personal exemption limit, you can use the [Estimate duty and taxes](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/dte-acl/est-cal-eng.html) calculator to find out how much you will have to pay when you bring the goods back to Canada.

You might find that even with the import duty and taxes, your goods may cost less overall if you purchase them in the US rather than in Canada. But, it is worthwhile to run the numbers beforehand to find out whether that will be true for your situation.